# How to get Rhythmbox working again

Tags: rhythmbox, ubuntu-mate, gstreamer, powerpc

My Rhythmbox stopped working today, I am using Ubuntu Mate 16.04 powerpc on a Powerbook G4. I installed Ubuntu Mate 16.04 in June and it has been working well. I use Rhythmbox a lot and until today it worked fine.

Now, when I try to play anything I either get "Nothing to play" or " Cannot connect to Gstreamer, check your installation."

I have purged, and re-installed Rhythmbox and the same problems remain. The files will still play on Clementine but I prefer Rhythmbox.

Since the original post, I have also tried Banshee and Gnome Music, neither worked. Banshee froze, when I tried to import my music and Gnome Music just froze on the initial "Hey DJ" screen. Clementine continues to work as it always has but it is fussier about the files than Rhythmbox and harder to use.

This is the output when I run rhythmbox from the terminal:

```
$ rhythmbox

(rhythmbox:3696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist

(rhythmbox:3696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist

(rhythmbox:3696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist

(rhythmbox:3696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist

(rhythmbox:3696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist

(rhythmbox:3696): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist

(rhythmbox:3696): Rhythmbox-WARNING **: Unable to grab media player keys: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files
```

Rhythmbox launches but media cannot be played and the error messages are given as above.

When I closed it, I got the following output:

```
(rhythmbox:3696): Rhythmbox-WARNING **: minus one
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is     discouraged.

(rhythmbox:3696): Gtk-WARNING **: mnemonic "s" wasn't removed for widget  (0x1042fa18)
```

The output after running

```
 apt-cache policy mate-settings-daemon{,-common} rhythmbox{,-data}     librhythmbox-core9
```

is:

```
mate-settings-daemon:
  Installed: 1.12.1-2build1
  Candidate: 1.12.1-2build1
  Version table:
 *** 1.12.1-2build1 500
        500 http://gb.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe powerpc Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
mate-settings-daemon-common:
  Installed: 1.12.1-2build1
  Candidate: 1.12.1-2build1
  Version table:
 *** 1.12.1-2build1 500
        500 http://gb.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/universe powerpc Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
rhythmbox:
  Installed: 3.3-1ubuntu7
  Candidate: 3.3-1ubuntu7
  Version table:
 *** 3.3-1ubuntu7 500
        500 http://gb.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main powerpc Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
rhythmbox-data:
  Installed: 3.3-1ubuntu7
  Candidate: 3.3-1ubuntu7
  Version table:
 *** 3.3-1ubuntu7 500
        500 http://gb.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main powerpc Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
librhythmbox-core9:
  Installed: 3.3-1ubuntu7
  Candidate: 3.3-1ubuntu7
  Version table:
 *** 3.3-1ubuntu7 500
        500 http://gb.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main powerpc Packages
                100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Is anyone else experiencing the same sort of problem on can offer any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: Do other GStreamer-based media players, particularly Totem, still work?

Comment: Yes, Totem works, i just installed it and tried it. It comes up as Videos although I ran it via the terminal as Totem.

Comment: Yes, the different name is normal. "Totem" is the historical and internal name of what's now "GNOME Videos". I also forgot to mention that MATE probably comes with its own fork of Totem. In any case, good to know that GStreamer works in general. Could you please try to start Rhythmbox in a terminal and add its output to your question? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I have added the output to my initial question.

Comment: That error message looks quite specific and helpful! Looks like either incompatible package versions or a corrupted package. Could you please run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mate-settings-daemon{,-common} rhythmbox{,-data} librhythmbox-core9` (if the command fails add its output to the question) and try again? Did the output of `rhythmbox` change? If that doesn't help please add the output of `apt-cache policy mate-settings-daemon{,-common} rhythmbox{,-data} librhythmbox-core9`.

Comment: when you removed and purged Rhythmbox did you remove the config files in Home directory as well? in some cases they could be the issue as well.

Comment: I couldn't find config files for Rhythmbox in the .config directory. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Are the config files for Rhythmbox under another name?

Answer (score 0):

This program was fixed by the last update. Rhythmbox is up and running again!

Comment: OK this it not funny, Rhythmbox is now broken again! Same message as before. Watch this space for updates...

Comment: I have submitted a bug report for this.

Answer (score 0):

Rhythmbox failed again after the last update.

This is the output from the terminal, similar to before...

```
$ rhythmbox

(rhythmbox:2976): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:2976): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:2976): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:2976): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:2976): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:2976): Gtk-WARNING **: Duplicate child name in GtkStack: Add to Playlist


(rhythmbox:2976): Rhythmbox-WARNING **: Unable to grab media player keys: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SettingsDaemon was not provided by any .service files

(rhythmbox:2976): Rhythmbox-WARNING **: minus one
Gtk-Message: 
GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```